# Call my function from JQUERY on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to cut down the repetitive code in JQUERY but can't figure out how to call my function from the "on-> click" function.

My function looks like this:

```
function myCheckAll(div, closer, finder){
    console.log(div+closer+finder);

      $(div).closest(closer).find(finder).prop('checked', this.checked); 
  }
```

And I'm trying to call it with something like this

```
  $("#check_all_0").on('click', myCheckAll("#check_all_0", "table", "input#val0"));
```

My problem is it doesn't work.
What I don't understand is:

1) I'm defining the function outside of the document-ready brackets.
Is this where I'm supposed to define it?

2) The console log is being called as soon as I load the page. Without clicking the target, and it doesn't call the function if I click the target.

I'm new to jquery and am probably doing something completely wrong, but would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: `"input#val0"` don't do that. Change to `"#val0"` the other way is slower and redundant.

Comment: if `finder` is a DOM ID there is no need for all the other jQuery.

Comment: Finder in this case would be #val0 now, what jQuery could I cut?

Comment: `$("#val0").prop('checked',this.checked);` is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("#check_all_0").on('click', myCheckAll("#check_all_0", "table", "input#val0"));
```

That will result in getting myCheckAll first called, and the result passed as event handler to jQuery. You would have to wrap it with a function:

```
$("#check_all_0").on('click', function() {
    myCheckAll("#check_all_0", "table", "input#val0"));
})
```

Also see the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: +1 for adding an explanation of the error and linking to a source.

Answer (score 3):

You may use a closure:

```
$("#check_all_0").on('click', function() {
    myCheckAll("#check_all_0", "table", "input#val0");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Although other answers are working, I believe you are looking for something like this:

```
$("input").on('click', {name: 'me'}, func);

function func(event) {
    console.log(event.data.name);
}
```

Adapted to your code:

```
$("#check_all_0").on('click', {div: "#check_all_0", closer: "table", finder:  "input#val0"}, myCheckAll);

function myCheckAll(event){
    console.log(event.data.div);
    console.log(event.data.closer);
    console.log(event.data.finder);
    $(event.data.div).closest(event.data.closer).find(avent.data.finder).prop('checked', this.checked); 
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nabil_kadimi/sdMQ2/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but it looks like a check all feature and while this isn't an answer to your question. It might help.

```
$('#check_all_0').on('click',function(e){
   $(this).closest('table').find(':checkbox').prop('checked',$(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

Without seeing the HTML it's not possible to know if that is correct, but you are using DOM IDs find things when maybe that's not the best way.